# Error: 'localhost refused to connect' when loading background map from osmnx folium in Google Coblab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, osmnx

I am using Google Colab. I am trying to add a background map to a network map via the built-in function `ox.plot_graph_folium` from osmnx.

However, the map is not shown up.

**My code:**

```
graph_map = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, popup_attribute='name', edge_width=2)
# save as html file then display map as an iframe
filepath = 'stockholm.html'
graph_map.save(filepath)
IFrame(filepath, width=900, height=500)
```

**Error message:**

localhost refused to connect.

[image]

**Attempt to fix it**

I have read a question that may be relevant in StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091645/serving-an-iframe-in-google-colab-notebook-localhost-refused-to-connect)). To be honest, I am an amateur. I didn't really understand what the code means. But still, I tried it and it doesn't work anyway.

```
!ln -s /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions /nbextensions
%cd /nbextensions
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you found some answers then you could add links in question (not in comment)

Comment: Just edited my question. Thanks for the reminder.